# Home Network Photo Server

Tags: photos, home-server

I am looking for a photo solution for our home network. We have several computers, running windows and OS X. I would like to store all of our photos in a central location, and have them be accessible from any machine. Most of our photos are currently in an iPhoto library, and ideally there would still be a way to import photos from the server to iPhoto easily. This can run really on any operating system, but it must be easily accessible for anybody. A gallery type view would be good, but also must allow direct file access and transfers. Anybody have a solution that works for them, or any ideas of what I could do?

Answer (score 1):

Solution for you is some kind of NAS.

Great NAS for home usage is from [Synology](http://synology.com).

Here is [Guide Exporting Itunes and Iphoto to DS](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=8414)

Answer (score 1):

I repurposed an old desktop for this very purpose.  I run FreeNAS from a USB stick which leaves my entire drive free for storage.  Only need a keyboard and monitor for initial setup, then manage via a network interface.

Answer (score 0):

Storing, sharing, and viewing your photos are all separate and distinct problems.  The photos can be stored on any of the machines on your network.  They can be shared from any of the machines as well.  How you choose to view them will depend on the individual machine as there are many different gallery viewing options available on both platforms.

That said, i recommend you store all your photos on one of your machines, share the folder across the network, and use a tool like [Google Picasa](http://picasa.google.com) to view.   If you don't want to have a machine on all the time for the express purpose of sharing, then get a Network Attached Storage drive (NAS) like [one of the many devices found here](http://www.newegg.com/store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=124&Tpk=NAS).

Answer (score 0):

I've been exploring Windows Home Server (WHS). You can either purchase a server, or, use an older computer and install Windows Home Server and make it your central server.

I've looked at Dell and HP. Do a Google search for Home Servers.